# Meteor app - Backbone router not getting called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, meteor, router

In my Meteor app Backbone routers are only working when the user is logged in (via the accounts-base package). It's strange. This router itself works fine. The `showSaying()`function isn't being called at all when the user is not logged in.

Below is the code in `client.js` within the client folder. Do I need to do something with sessions or auto-publishing?

```
AphorismView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: "#aphorism-item",
initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    this.$el.append("<p style='height:600px; background-color:blue;'>hi</p>");
}
});

// Creates a route to view the selected aphorism
var Aphorism = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {       
        "saying/:id": "showSaying"
    },
    showSaying: function (id) {
        var aphorism_view = new AphorismView();
        alert('Saying id ' + id + '.');
  }
});

//establishes the router
appRouter = new Aphorism;

//Sets up backbone
Meteor.startup(function () {
    filepicker.setKey("AerIOvsmAQRGaNdEv0judz");
    filepicker.constructWidget(document.getElementById('attachment'));
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
});
```

Comment: I suspect this has to do with load speed/order and that when logged in, loading takes longer, leading to appRouter being ready on time. Try putting the appRouter declaration inside Meteor.startup.

Comment: tried this Rahul - didn't work

Comment: I haven't worked on Win8 Metro Apps yet,so I don't know if there is a development console available like in Browsers. If there is, I'd invoke the `appRouter = new Aphorism;` just before `Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});` and assign the appRoute to a global variable to see if it is initialised at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue doesn't seem like a Backbone.js issue at all.

Have you tried putting a console.log statement inside the `startup()` callback to verify that it's actually being called in all cases? If not, then that's between you and Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried waiting for the DOM to be ready? eg: `$( Backbone.history.start )`

Answer (score 1):

Try pulling the Backbone history declaration outside of `Meteor.start`. There's no reason for it to be there. Also, I believe that `showSaying` will only be called if you go to a route that has the `id` parameter (i.e., you can't just go to `http://app/saying/`).

In addition, you might need to manually call `approuter.navigate` in order for the router to work if you're trying to navigate programmatically. (I don't know if you are, but it could be the problem).

Other than that, I can't find any issues with this specific piece of code. The problem might be somewhere else, if nothing I suggested solves it.

For an example of a working router implementation, you could look at https://github.com/Benaiah/Athenaeum/blob/master/client/router.coffee (disclaimer: it's from an app I'm writing) and try to find any other differences.

Hope that helps.